# Git init и смена work tree

Tags: git

Только начал изучать git и сразу захотелось сменить рабочую директорию (если ничего не напутал в терминологии).
Если делаю `git init`, то у меня создается заполненная `c:\Users\%USER_NAME%\.git`.

Прочел, что можно определить эту директорию через environment variables: %GIT_DIR%
Определил и создал папку на d:\GIT
После выполнения `git init` создаются все нужные папки и файлы в `d:\GIT`
После выполнения `git status` вылетает `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`

Как дать понять интерпретатору, что я сменил раз и навсегда work tree?

Answer (score 8):

Не нужно ничего глобально задавать в переменных окружения. Просто перейдите в ту папку, в которой хотите создать репозиторий, и выполните `git init` там. И впоследствии, когда будете работать с этим репозиторием, работайте только в этой папке.

Comment: благодарю!